# BadPaddingException in Android while decryption of images encrypted with stand alone java program

Tags: android, encryption

I am encrypting images in assets folder with following code and trying to decrypt in apk. (I am doing this just to avoid easy copying of images with just unzip of apk file). I know i will have the key as part of apk.

I used and tested below code for encrypting the images with stand alone java program. (I tested them by decrpyting and it is working fine in stand alone java program.

Encryption

```
         byte[] incrept = simpleCrypto.encrypt(KEY, simpleCrypto.getImageFile("E:/aeroplane.png"));


         //Store encrypted file in SD card of your mobile with name vincent.mp3.
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:/out-aeroplane.png"));
          fos.write(incrept);
          fos.close();
```

Decryption

```
        byte[] decrpt = simpleCrypto.decrypt(KEY, simpleCrypto.getImageFile("E:/out-aeroplane.png"));

          //Store encrypted file in SD card of your mobile with name vincent.mp3.
          FileOutputStream fosdecrypt = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:/outdecrypt-aeroplane.png"));


          fosdecrypt.write(decrpt);
          fosdecrypt.close();
```

Encrypt Decrypt logic

```
   public byte[]   getImageFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
{
  byte[] Image_data = null;
  byte[] inarry = null;

    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    FileInputStream  is = new FileInputStream (file); // use recorded file instead of getting file from assets folder.
        int length = is.available();
        Image_data = new byte[length];

        int bytesRead;
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(Image_data)) != -1)
        {
            output.write(Image_data, 0, bytesRead);
        }
      inarry = output.toByteArray();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

return inarry;
}


public  byte[] encrypt(String seed, byte[] cleartext) throws Exception {

    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext);
      //  return toHex(result);
        return result;
}

public  byte[] decrypt(String seed, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] enc = encrypted;
        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);

        return result;
}

//done
private  byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(128, sr); 
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    return raw;
} 


private  byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
}

private  byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
}
```

In my apk file after getting the image as InputStream, I am decrypting them after converting them as byte array. Again I am converting the decrypted byte array to input stream for BitmapFactory.decode. I tried both decodeByteArray and decodeStream. Both not working.

Image is encrypted with stand alone java program and it is decrypted in apk. (If i decrypt in stand alone java program, it is working fine.)

I am getting error saying  **Failed to decode Stream javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted**

```
    public static Bitmap readBitmap(InputStream input) {
    if (input == null)
        return null;

    try {
        String KEY = "kumar";

        byte[] inarry =IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
        byte[] decrpt = SquarksCryptUtil.decrypt(KEY, inarry);

    InputStream cleanStream = null;

    cleanStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decrpt);

     //   return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cleanStream);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decrpt, 0, decrpt.length);


       // return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(FILE_NAME, "Failed to decode Stream " + e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        close(input);
    }
```

}

Comment: Don't call `getBytes()`; it will return different bytes on different platforms.  Use an encoding.

Comment: You need to pass a unique consistent IV.

Comment: I tried to used IvParameterSpec as below and got error saying "ECB mode cannot use IV"
String iv = "fedcba9876543210";
     IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
     
     SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
     cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec,ivspec);

Comment: You should use CBC; ECB is not secure.

Comment: Cryptography is _hard_; you need to learn how it works before you can use it properly.  Otherwise, you are very likely to end up with easily breakable crypto.

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you are facing is because you are assuming that the random number generates the same key on each platform. This issue is due to the fact that there is a very bad example on the internet that uses `SecureRandom` as a key derivation function, which it is *not*. `SecureRandom` is not even well defined if the seed is set directly. You can use PBKDF2 instead of the incorrect key derivation function on both sides, there should be enough pointers on stackoverflow on how to perform PBKDF2 key derivation using Java.

The best thing to do is to decrypt the images on the SE platform and then re-encrypt them correctly using PBKDF2. Currently, the way the key is derived is only specified in the source code of the Sun implementation of `"SHA1PRNG"`. That's not a good foundation at all.

Furthermore you need to assure that there are no platform dependencies during encryption/decryption, as others already have pointed out.